# How to use a specific path to write/read data to firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to use dynamic paths selected by the user in my app to access/write data to my db. Sort of like a file path that the user can type, Eg: "users/mike/age". Using this string, I need to fetch as well as write data to the path in the db. Is there any way this is possible??

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is pretty vague as Firestore works with Collections and Documents - which can be thought of similar to a path but your app controls where there user writes their data. Are you talking about creating Collections and then documents for the user to store their data? If so, did you go through the getting started guides?

Comment: Oh, actually, i needed to allow the user to select a route navigating through my database(ik it's bad practise), so wanted to select docs from firestore using a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of strange, but you could split the string then refactor with firebase path.

```
String pathStr = 'users/mike/age';
List<String> list = pathStr.split('/'); //now we have a list with the fields.
var ref;
switch (list.length) {
  case 0:
    break;
  case 1:
    ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(list[0]);
    break;
  case 2:
    ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(list[0]).doc(list[1]);
    break;  
  case 3:
    ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(list[0]).doc(list[1]).collection(list[2]);
    break;    
  case 4:
    ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(list[0]).doc(list[1]).collection(list[2]).doc(list[3]);
    break;      
  default: ref = null;
}
//Do whatevar with the ref path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase works in a way like

> Collections/Documents/Collections/Documents ...

You can create a `Document` & `Collection` dynamically in firebase, But you can not fetch any collection if are not known the name of `Collection`.

It means if there is a `List of Documents` in a `Collection` you can fetch the list by using its parent collection name but a `List of Collection` nested under a Document can not be fetched unless you are known to names.

For Example,
if there is a path `users/mike/age`. You can fetch `users` because you know that you created a `Collection` named `users` and all of its Documents like `mike` can also be fetched. But if you have not known the age of user. You cannot fetch it.