# Get Firebase Document Snapshot to a Map

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I Have to use Map the Snapshot as this method

```
     Stream<List<writeTime>> readDataStream() {
        final monthData = dateTimeNow('yyyyMMdd');
        print(monthData);
        final path = APIPath.rdatapath(user);
        final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(path);
        final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
        return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((snapshot) => writeTime.fromMap(snapshot.data()))
            .toList());
      }
```

But Recently I have to Get a Specific Document and I tried this code

```
    Stream<List<writeTime>> readDataStream() {
        final monthData = dateTimeNow('yyyyMMdd');
        print(monthData);
        final path = APIPath.rdatapath(user);
        final reference =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(monthData);
        final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
        return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((snapshot) => writeTime.fromMap(snapshot.data()))
            .toList());
      }
```

But I have a error in here

```
 return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.**docs**
            .map((snapshot) => writeTime.fromMap(snapshot.data()))
            .toList());
```

And the error is

```
The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.
```

And I used This map to get data

```
    factory writeTime.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
        if (data == null) {
          throw AssertionError('data must not be null');
        }
        final int thour = data['thour'];
        final int tmin = data["tmin"];
        final int chour = data['chour'];
        final int cmin = data["cmin"];
        return writeTime(thour: thour, tmin: tmin, chour: chour, cmin: cmin);
      }
```

How I fix this?

Comment: Please check the answer provided on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966912/how-to-use-a-specific-path-to-write-read-data-to-firestore-in-flutter & https://www.androidbugfix.com/2021/12/the-getter-isn-defined-for-type.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
snapshot.data!.docs.map((snap)=>writeTime.fromMap(snap))).toList();
```

Comment: No Brother,,
I think you said to apply it like this
   return snapshots.map((snapshot) => 
        snapshots.data!.docs.map((snap)=>writeTime.fromMap(snap))).toList();

and it throw me arror as A value of type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be returned from the method 'readDataStream' because it has a return type of 'Stream<List<writeTime>>'.
So what I need to do?

Comment: can i see the writeTime.fromMap method?

Comment: ohhh i forget its a stream, try snapshot.docs.map((snap)=>writeTime.fromMap(snap.data())).toList();

Comment: I think there are no different between my original code and the your code ??? and It Still Not working

Comment: please show me this  writeTime.fromMap method i want to check something